# Desktop internet shortcut opens as text file

Tags: 12.04, browser, .desktop

I have two very similar .desktop launcher files that are to be used as internet shortcuts.  When I double click on one file it opens properly in a webbrowser as I would like.  When I double click on the other, it opens in a text editor which I do NOT like.  How do I change this?

Good shortcut opens in browser:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Safari Books
Type=Link
URL=http://hdl.library.upenn.edu/1017/7026
Icon=text-html
Name[en_US]=Safari Books
```

Bad shortcut opens in text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Learning Python
Type=Link
URL=http://proquestcombo.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9780596805395
Icon=text-html
Name[en_US]=Learning Python
```

Comment: @BiggJJ he means that the URL is downloaded but opens in gedit instead of a browser (since it is an XML file)

Comment: compare thier file permissions with ls -l

Comment: I have copied your second `.desktop` file and made the test, results: the first time I clicked it was opened in Firefox (good), now the second time (and the next...) it does open in GEdit. Not sure but this might actually be a bug. Try reporting it. Curiously Nautilus opens a dialog offering the possibility to cancel.

Comment: Seriously, this is a bug in Nautilus in my opinion. This behavior is quite unexpected.

Comment: thanks for feedback!  I will look into reporting as a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a good solution, but I have a solution. You see, the desktop entry specification does not determine the *viewer* or mime type for a link. A link can be an image, a document, whatever, and the correct viewer will be chosen based on what the file is. And so it happens that this link opens with an editor (and not a browser). You have two options.

However, here is a little change that will result in the correct behavior, although it is ugly. Modify the  desktop entry like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Learning Python
Type=Application
Exec=xdg-open http://proquestcombo.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9780596805395
Icon=text-html
MimeType=text/html
Name[en_US]=Learning Python
```

It will look the same, but it will be an application launcher. Just remember to set the permissions to execute in that case!

Comment: Instead of "Firefox", you can type "xdg-open", which will make your default browser open the link.

Comment: Yeah. But I still do not understand why the url opens in the editor.

Comment: Don't forget to chmod +x the desktop file.  That tripped me up.  Must read instructions more carefully :)