# Website launcher in Nautilus, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: launcher, webbrowser-app

I would like to create a file that when double clicked launches a website in the default web browser. I have found that `.desktop` files can do this, but apparently they no longer work in Ubuntu 22.04.

How can this be done?

Comment: The instructions given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/353952/956007) still work in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work for me. I made the `.desktop` file executable. Do I have to do something extra for it to open the website on double click?

Comment: I double checked and the results are disappointing. Turns out this approach only works from Nemo file manager. From Nautilus it opens the text file (right click + run as program does nothing). In Thunar nothing happens. If I place it on the desktop, it says "broken desktop file". Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an html file that launches in the default browser and immediately redirects to your target website with the `http-equiv=refresh` attribute on the `<meta>` element. The target website address goes to the `content` attribute which must be a non-negative integer followed by the string `';url='`, and your URL. The integer is the number of seconds until the page should redirect - in this case `0` is a convenient value.

If you have a link to your website on a page in Firefox, you can actually drag the link and drop it on the desktop to create such a file (this is how I accidentally found this solution while playing around with links and desktop launcher files). Or, create the file manually.

For example the following file will open and redirect to askubuntu.com:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://askubuntu.com" />
  </head>
<body></body>
</html>
```